# Usage of っぺら and っぺらい

Tags: grammar, nuances, adjectives, suffixes

Are both っぺら and っぺらい used in the same way to emphazise an adjective? Is there any difference between them?

For example: 薄っぺら/薄っぺらい

Can you use っぺら and っぺらい to every adjective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking as if っぺら(い) were a kind of suffix, but it's not a suffix that can emphasize something. Actually, the only adjective I can think of that contains っぺら(い) is 薄っぺら(い).

Regarding 薄っぺらな (na-adjective) vs 薄っぺらい (i-adjective), yes, they are interchangeable and have the same meaning. There is a slangy i-adjective [ペラい](http://zokugo-dict.com/29he/perai.htm), but this is never used as a na-adjective (ペラな is wrong).

Comment: I'm curious about the derivation.  There's 半【はん】ぺら and ぺらぺら, referencing paper or other flat things. Is that where this (っ)ぺら(い) suffixing element comes from?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped a lot. It's true that I knew about っぺら(い) because of 薄っぺら(い), but looking for っぺら(い) on Google before opening this post, I also found things like ヤングっぺら or のっぺらい人. For that reason, I thought that っぺら(い) may be a kind of suffix.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I believe those are all etymologically related to [ぺらぺら](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%A9).

Comment: @kanachan I have no idea what ヤングっぺら can mean... のっぺらい is probably a slangy adjective derived from [のっぺらぼう](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BA%E3%82%89%E3%81%BC%E3%81%86), but I don't know its etymology.

Comment: @naruto Ok, I see! Thanks a lot for your answer. :)